# CSS How to put 4 divs on each side of a parent div

Tags: html, css

I wish to include 4 divs inside a parent div in the following manner:

[image]

I could use fixed position and set right/left/top/bottom = 0 accordingly for each child div if they were not inside in a div, but right now, I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: you can use absolute position for the 4 divs and relative position for parent div then set the position and dimensions of the 4 divs appropriately. give this a try.

Comment: Better if you use grid view

Comment: Is it a requirement for those elements to be in that specific order (div3 -> div2 -> div4 -> div1)?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes, I want them to take up equal space.

Comment: @nOp That wasn't really my question - but I realise it doesn't really matter since once you have a solution or an idea of how to achieve this it can be applied to or with any order.

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/17awkegt/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes that works also! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, but I'm not sure how this will fare in responsiveness since the parent has fixed sizes, but the child div should be able to adapt if the parent changes size. Some css can be combined, but I separated them all for reference

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.div4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">
    DIV1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    DIV2
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    DIV3
  </div>
  <div class="div4">
    DIV4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. When the parent div is rectangular, however, one need to adjust the width and height for each div in order to make the proportions reasonable !

Comment: That's true, that is why it is not really good in responsiveness. I think you will be needing the help of javascript for dynamic parent

Answer (score 1):

Consider utilizing `absolute` positioning on nested `div` elements and offsetting their positions, within the containing element, appropriately and as required by declaring `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties respectively.

**Code Snippet Demonstration**

*Note:*
In the below demonstration, a containing element, with *resizing* properties, has been wrapped around the element in question, *to demonstrate the responsive behaviour of this method.*

Resize the element manually by clicking the icon, in the bottom-left corner of the containing element, and dragging vertically or horizontally.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

.outer {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; /* required */
}

.outer-wrapper { /* purely for the sake of responsive demonstration */
  padding: 10px;
  resize: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px dashed gray;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.outer div {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.outer div:nth-child(odd) {
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
}

.outer div:nth-child(even) {
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}

.outer div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ed1c24;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.outer div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #00a2e8;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.outer div:nth-child(3) {
    background: #22b14c;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.outer div:nth-child(4) {
    background: #b97a57;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper"> 
  <div class="outer">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
.parent>div{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center; 
}
.one{ 
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;  
}
.two{  
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;  
}
.three{  
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;  
}
.four{  
  background-color: brown;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"> Div1</div>
  <div class="two">Div2</div>
  <div class="three">Div3</div>
  <div class="four">Div4</div>
</div>
```